# How to keep formula to use the same reference when inserting cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an worksheet with several formulas. Actually fairly simple ones, with `SUM, AVERAGE, MAX and MIN` and so on. However, when new data comes in, I need to insert the new row at the top. 
The `AVERAGE, MIN and MAX` cells are above the first data entry. 
So, when I insert a row the MIN & MAX functions keep row 13 as their first row, that's good. However, the AVERAGE function, changes to the next row...
I don't get anything working to keep the first 12 periods as average (starting row 13)

I tried making the column a table -> no luck
I tried $ reference `(AVERAGE($C$13:$C$24) ->` no luck 
I tried include `OFFSET`, but the `OFFSET` itself will be changed to `C14` when inserting the row -> no luck

I expect all my formulas to keep the original range when inserting rows

BUT! when the `MAX` function is used, it should be the `MAX` of all the values, including the new value...to make it worse ;-)

Comment: So you need always, let's say, the average of the first 13 rows of data?

Comment: If you want always to get the average of `C13:C24`, even if you insert new rows, use INDIRECT. You can do `AVERAGE(INDIRECT("C13:C24"))`. This will return **always** the average of the range `C13:C24`

Comment: Please try, for example: `=AVERAGE(INDEX($C:$C,13):INDEX($C:$C,24))`.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns why not post it as a proper answer? it will help others that may have a similar question :)

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX($C:$C,13):INDEX($C:$C,24))
```

would evaluate to `=AVERAGE($C$13:$C$24)` and won't increase/decrease in size, while:

```
=MAX(INDEX($C:$C,13):$C24)
```

would increase in range when adding a new row but will start at `C13`.

Comment: =AVERAGE(INDEX($C:$C;11;):INDEX($C:$C;23;))  I had to use the semicolon, this seems to work.

Comment: In additon, when I have conditional formatting to my cells (like C11 - C192) and I insert the row, I also have to re-apply the conditional formatting. Is there a similar solution for this as well?

Comment: Yes there is, but I'm afk at the moment. What conditonal formatting are you applying? With what rule

Comment: Ok, I use the 3 color formatting for coloring my cells. So the highest value in the selected range turns red, the lowest value is green and all in between fades between red - white - green. But again, when I add a row on top, the new row is not included in the cond. formatting

Comment: You can have a formula to have some conditional formatting rule, but not a standard like you are using I'm afraid. It's quite a user-unfriendly feature I find.

Comment: @Jasper the range for **conditional formatting** will be updated automatically once you insert new rows on top of the original range. It cannot be "locked" to specific range unfortunately at least not in my version of Excel which is 2016. A work around this is to create a dashboard like report to show the values in a new worksheet which was formula-linked to C13:C24 and apply conditional formatting on the new range whose values will be updated once you have updated the original worksheet.